# Remove 0.*I in imported table

Tags: list-manipulation

I imported some table containing elements with 0.*I. I tried to remove this 0.*I by using ./{"0.*I" -> 0}, however, it did not work. Could you please tell me how to remove it?

Edit. I created a table which includes elements with 0.I,

```
tableexample = {{11+0.I},{12+0.I}};
```

and then exported it in an external file:

```
Export["tableexample.dat",tableexample,"Table"];
```

After importing,

```
imported = Import["tableexample.dat","Table"];
```

the 0.I is not interpreted as a number, rather it is a text. In my case instead of tableexample I have very large table, and therefore exporting and importing time is very large, and therefore it would be preferable for me to remove 0.I post factum, after importing the table with 0.*I being not a number.

Comment: Did you try `Chop`, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198179/why-can-0-i-appear#comment513324_198179 ?

Comment: @Szabolcs : it did not work since 0.*I is not a number in the imported table.

Comment: This really can't be answered without a clear explanation of the problem, accompanied by [a small example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2131/12).

Comment: @Szabolcs : I've added some explanation.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not possible to understand what *exactly* you are doing. Importing and exporting can be done in a gazillion way. Having an example is critical.

Comment: Otherwise all I could say is: export to MX format and nothing will be converted to a string.

Comment: @Szabolcs : I have added a toy example.

Comment: `Chop` before you `Export`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : the problem is that exporting and importing takes a very long time. I have already imported a file and would like to remove 0.*I at this stage.

Comment: @JohnTaylor I see. If you run `FullForm[imported]` (in your MWE), what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to get rid of numbers close to zero.
- Avoid exporting such data using the `"Table"` format, as it cannot handle complex numbers. If you will only read this data with Mathematica, consider the WDX format for wide compatibility and longer term storage, or the MX format for the short term. MX is very fast.
- If you already wrote this file, use `ToExpression@Import[..., "Table"]` to get proper numbers. Then use `Chop`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like this code:

```
Rationalize /@ ToExpression /@ imported
```

which returns the result

```
{{11}, {12}}
```

or replace `Rationalize` with some other function such as `Chop`. Without some real examples of your data it is not possible to be more specific about what needs to be done.

By the way, you can use `ExportString[]` and `ImportString[]` to test example code using strings instead of external files.